# OperationalError (1054, "Unknown column 'month' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm annotating price per month from my database, and I'm facing this error, I'm trying to figure out why, so in my model I have a `DateTimeField`, I have tried playing with data inside shell and everything is fine, I have it there, I also tried to look over db with MySQL Workbench and data is there, [Full traceback](http://dpaste.com/1QPSGKE) and the rest of the code, can someone explain what is wrong with my annotation?

models.py

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
from django.db import connection

from projects.models import Project
from .services import CurrencyConversionService



class ProjectStatisticsList(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'statistics/statistics_list.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectStatisticsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql("year", "month")
        total_price_per_month = Project.objects.extra({"month": truncate_month}).values("month").annotate(sum_price=Sum("price_aux"))

        context['total_price_per_month'] = total_price_per_month
        return context
```

And in template:

```
<tr>
    {% for data in total_price_per_month %}
   <th class="aligh-left"> </th>
    {% endfor %}
   <td>Month: {{ data.month }}</td>
    <td>Price: {{ data.sum_price }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but the `data.month` is outside the scope of the for-loop of which `data` is the loop variable.

Comment: What exactly do you want to query for. This does not seem like sth. the ORM couldn't handle.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I want to query my total project price per month, and make a table of 12 month so I can show total price for each months

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use fields from `extra` in a `values` clause.

But this is really the wrong way to do it. You should be using Django's database function support; specifically, the [`extract` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#extract):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract
Project.objects.annotate(month=Extract('created', 'month').values("month").annotate(sum_price=Sum("price_aux"))
```

Comment: Ah, I'm using `django` version 1.8.9, and this is added in 1.10