# Django annotate price per month

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to refer this to my other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181399/operationalerror-1054-unknown-column-month-in-field-list) here on SO, so I'm trying to display price per month and make a table with 12 months, a row with total project income per month, so I have successfully calculated my price using

`context["price_aux"] = Project.objects.annotate().aggregate(Sum("price_aux"))`

I can display my data in a table and just make a row of total for that, but as you can see from my previous question I want to annotate this per month and make a table and then display total for month, but I have really hard time understanding how can I extract this from my database, so what is the proper way for doing this in `django==1.8+`, I see that in recent version they have added [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#extract), but I can not use it in 1.8, second thing is `django extra` they stated here [Use this method as a last resort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#extra), so can you explain me how can I make this work.

Comment: Why don't you use a table with two columns, one for month and one for price. Then you can simply select the price by month.

Comment: I'm using something like that, but I have a hard time extracting moth from db, can make a small example?

Comment: Assuming your model is called `Prices` and has two fields `month` and `price` then you do `ppm = Prices.objects.filter(month=1)[0]`. `ppm.price` gives you the actual price then.

Comment: ok, the problem is that I have `created` field which is DateTimeField, and what I do that I've got `TypeError: expected string to buffer`, I can use `created__month`, but then I've got list `index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you add a field to your model, as it isn't possible to use `__month` in `.values_list`. Values_list can be used to group your queries before annotation.

Field could be something like.

```
year_month = models.CharField(index=True)
```

You could overwrite the save method on your model and do something like

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # Not sure if auto_add_now already set the value, could use timezone.now()
    if not self.id:  # thus not saved yet
        self.year_month = self.created_at.strftime("%Y%m")
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now its possible to annotate your prices.

```
Project.objects.values_list('year_month').annotate(price_sum=Sum("price_aux"))
```

If you need more info, I believe your could expand the values_list.

```
Project.objects.values_list('year_month').annotate(price_sum=Sum("price_aux")) \
    .values_list('name', 'year_month', 'price_sum')
```

Doing it without adding field is ofcourse possible. Let say you want the past year.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def my_list_view(request):
    end = timezone.now()
    # note, could do some weird stuff in years with 366 days
    begin = (end - datetime.timedelta(days=365)).replace(day=1)  

    container = {}
    while begin < end:
        container[begin.strftime("%Y%m")] = 0
        begin = (begin + datetime.timedelta(weeks=5).replace(day=1)

    for project in Project.objects.iterator():
        container[project.created_at.strftime("%Y%m")] += price

    # Now you can render your template
```

Comment: Ok, is it worth doing this calculation by *hand*, using iterator() in my `ListView` and not add new field in `models.py`, this i interesting nevertheless I will try it, I was just wondering about this more python way of calculating price per month

Comment: I'm using generic `ListView` for this template, so I can maybe make a `mixin` and do this calculation

Comment: Never made use of `ListView`, also never heared about a mixin within Django, but glad my answer helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Say your model is called `Prices` and has two fields `date` and `price` where `date` is a datetime field. Then you can use `date__month` (note the double underscore) as a keyword argument to query methods (see the docs for [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)).

You can retrieve the price by month via

```
Prices.objects.get(date__month=1).price
```